# Scraper has stopped working, probably a small issue but cannot find the issue

Tags: vba, scraper

This scraper should return the data suggesting how many properties show up in the search.

It was working until I opened it this morning, the class hasn't changed but for some reason, it will not return any data into the cell stated.

```
Sub ZPLA2()

  Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4

    Dim j As Integer

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim Doc As IHTMLDocument
    Dim xcolElements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim ell As IHTMLElement

    Dim pn As Integer
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate "http://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/london/w1/west-end-mayfair-soho-marylebone-south/?beds_max=0&beds_min=0&include_retirement_homes=true&include_shared_ownership=true&new_homes=include&price_max=200000&price_min=50000&q=w1&radius=20&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=refine"
    ' Do
    'DoEvents
    'Loop Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:07"))
    Set Doc = ie.Document

    Set xcolElements = Doc.getElementsByClassName("split3l result-count")

    For Each ell In xcolElements

      Sheet2.Range("d2").Value = ell.innerText
      On Error GoTo skip

    Next

skip:
    ie.Quit
    Set el = Nothing
    Set xcolElements = Nothing
    Set Doc = Nothing
    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 Set xcolElements = Doc.getElementsByClassName("split3l result-count")
```

with:

```
Set xcolElements = Doc.getElementsByClassName("listing-results-utils-count")
```

Remember to use IE Developer Tools not Chrome etc. as you are in fact utilizing the IE browser in VBA in the code above.